# Extract the regression model(s) used by MatchThem for propensity matching on multiply imputed data

Tags: r, imputation, propensity-score-matching

I have used the MatchThem package to propensity match a multiply imputed dataset, which produces a `mimids` object `foo`.

I would like to extract the glm used by MatchThem to do the propensity matching, so I can report it's properties. However, because there are multiple models (one for each imputation), I think these will need to be pooled with Rubin's rules to produce a valid summary model.

The glm for each imputation can be found at `foo$models[[n]]$model`, but `MatchThem::pool()` only works on `mimira` or `mira` objects, which these are not.

I have tried extracting the models into a list and pooling that, which "works", insofar that it executes without an error (`mice::pool` accepts a list), but I am not sure if this is a good approach and am wondering if there is a better way?

```
bar <-  foo$models %>%
    map(magrittr::extract2, "model")

pooled <- mice::pool(bar)
```

Comment: I don't understand why `pool()` on the `mimira` object doesn't give you what you want. What are you trying to compute that is not available in the `pool()` output? Also note there is no single pooled model; there are coefficients from the models that are pooled. You can't pool residuals or R2 or model comparison statistics, etc., like you can coefficients using Rubin's rules.

Comment: Hi Noah - I don't have a `mimira` object because there hasn't been (or rather, I don't want to pull the results of) the subsequent analysis.

What I am after is the details/coefficients of the model that was used to perform the matching, i.e. the one that was specified in `matchthem()`.

Comment: You mean the propensity score model? That model has no interpretation and the coefficients should not be reported. It has no validity and provides no information about the selection process or the performance of the model at reducing bias. Its sole purpose is to yield propensity scores that achieve balance. So I would recommend against your plan. You can always just fit your own models without using `MatchThem`, e.g., `with(imp, glm(treat ~ x1 + x2 + x3, family = binomial))`, which returns a `mira` object. You can also use `as.mira()` on a list of model objects.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. If you put it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted. However, as a followup - why does the PS model provide no information about the matching process? My thought was that it illustrated relative importance of different variables in generating the PS. I had also thought about doing as you suggest (fitting the same model to `imp`) - but if the purpose is to illustrate the influence of different variables then won't that have the same issues with interpretation that you mentioned?

Comment: If you ask "Why don't people report the coefficients of their propensity score model?" on CrossValidated, I will give you a thorough answer to that question. In short, 1) there are many different sets of model coefficients that could have given you balance after matching, so the one you found is not not special. 2) The coefficients are simply a function of the initial imbalance and the covariance between covariates, the former of which should be reported anyway and the latter of which is irrelevant.

Comment: Both of those make sense enough to me, I'll stick with listing the variables used and providing the imbalance data.